# Laravel forge loosing connection to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-forge

I realise this may not be a huge amount of informaiton but I am getting the error when trying to login:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = email@example.com limit 1)
```

The only pages I can access are ones that are outside the login area and do not have any database queries.

This currently seems to happen every few days. The last time it happened was over the weekend and I know that no-one would have been on the site/made any changes at this time. We also do not have any crons/schedules running that effect the database.

I can fix it by restarting SQL but it only seems to last for a few days each time before loosing the connection again.

Can anyone suggest what this could be or where I should start debugging it?

Comment: Take a look here (both answers and comments): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904190/mysql-socket-refuses-connection-after-thousands-of-successive-connections Also check mysql logs.

Comment: You may have reached your storage limit on the server. Free some space and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The DB does only have a few thousand rows of data however, and when this happens seems to often be when the database is 100% dormant. Only a few of us are using this site and it is not used over the weekend, which is the last time it happened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729170/how-to-know-about-mysql-refused-connections

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in this case I was running out of memory due to Redis.

Logs in /var/logs/mysql helped find this. Sorry if it was a stupid question!